# How to unzip files from a zipped folder at FTP location using ADFv2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a zipped folder at FTP location and want to unzip it at blob location. But how to achieve the same? I have no idea on it. Please tell me hows to achieve the same.

Comment: have you tried any of the first google results on "azure data factory extract zip"? Like here https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/cloud-data/using-copy-wizard-azure-data-factory/

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please reference this tutorial: [Copy data from FTP server by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-ftp).

This article outlines how to copy data from FTP server.

Specifically, this FTP connector supports:

- Copying files using Basic or Anonymous authentication.
- Copying files as-is or parsing files with the [supported file formats
  and compression codecs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs).

Azure Data Factory supports compress/decompress zip data during copy. Legacy compress model are still supported as-is for backward compatibility.

[image]

You can follow this steps:

[image]

Choose the file `Compress type`, Data Factory will help unzip it.
[image]

Reference tutorial:

1. [Using the Copy Wizard for the Azure Data Factory](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/cloud-data/using-copy-wizard-azure-data-factory/)
2. [Moving data processing to the cloud – part 1 – Azure Data
   Factory](https://www.future-processing.pl/blog/moving-data-processing/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Leon's answer is correct - just for clarity, set the compression on your FTP Source DataSet to "ZipDeflate" [for standard .zip files] and the compression on your Blob Sink DataSet to "None". The Copy activity will unzip the underlying files into a virtual folder in Blob Storage with the zip file name.